# InstanceName and InstanceID in Quartz.Net Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, quartz.net

I am working on creating a Scheduler using Quartz.Net.

While Configuring it, I am using two properties as below:

```
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TestScheduler2";
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_two";
```

I have used them but don't know what exactly they do.
Referred Quartz.Net official website but the information provided is not enough.

Please explain the use of these two configuration properties.

Answer (score 2):

From [Java version's configuration guide](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigMain):

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName

Can be any string, and the value has no meaning to the scheduler itself - but rather serves as a mechanism for client code to distinguish schedulers when multiple instances are used within the same program. If you are using the clustering features, you must use the same name for every instance in the cluster that is 'logically' the same Scheduler.

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId

Can be any string, but must be unique for all schedulers working as if they are the same 'logical' Scheduler within a cluster. You may use the value "AUTO" as the instanceId if you wish the Id to be generated for you. Or the value "SYS_PROP" if you want the value to come from the system property "org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId".